# How to append to existing xml file as a set of attributes

Tags: c#, xml, set, append

here is the xml file what i want to get. it contains disaster details numbere 01,02,03 and onwards. disasters are identified by disaster id.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<disasters>
  <disaster ID="001"
      disaterType="Flood"
      location="Matara"
      date="20-01-2012"
      noOfVictims="245">
      <victims>
          <victim type="adult"
               gender="male"
               amount="46"
               />
        <victim type="children"
             gender="female"
             amount="460"/>
      </victims>
          <requiredItems>
             <requiredItem type="Food"
                  itemName="Rice" 
                  description="null"
                  quantity="367"/>
             <requiredItem type="Stationary"
                  itemName="Pens"
                  description="null"
                  quantity="87"/>
          </requiredItems>
  </disaster>
  <disaster ID="002" // This is a separate disaster detail list
     disaterType="Tsunami"
     location="Galle"
     date="10-05-2009"
     noOfVictims="845">
      <victims>
          <victim type="children"
               gender="male"
               amount="46"
               />
          <victim type="children"
               gender="female"
               amount="460"/>
      </victims>
         <requiredItems>
           <requiredItem type="Clothes"
                itemName="Tshirts"
                description="male"
                quantity="67"/>
           <requiredItem type="Food"
                itemName="bread"
                description="null"
                quantity="37"/>
         </requiredItems>  
  </disaster> // end of the second list of disaster details
</disasters>
```

here is my code. but it only add new disaster id. The rest of the details append incorrectly. the ** code is going to append to the first disaster id but i want to add them to the second disaster and identify them as a new disaster.
Thanks in advance

```
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load("C:\\4 ITP la laaa\\me doing\\disasters.xml");
            XmlNode xNode = xDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "disaster", "");
            XmlAttribute id = xDoc.CreateAttribute("ID");
            XmlAttribute disaterType = xDoc.CreateAttribute("value");
            XmlAttribute location = xDoc.CreateAttribute("value1");
            XmlAttribute date = xDoc.CreateAttribute("value2");
            XmlAttribute noOfVictims = xDoc.CreateAttribute("value3");
            id.Value = "001";
            disaterType.Value = "Flood";
            date.Value = " value1";
            noOfVictims.Value = "date";
            xNode.Attributes.Append(id);
            xNode.Attributes.Append(disaterType);
            --
            --

            XmlNode xNode1 = xDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "victims", "");
            XmlAttribute type = xDoc.CreateAttribute("type");

            type.Value = "adult";
            gender.Value = "male";
            value.Value = "46";
            --
            --
            xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("disasters")[0].InsertAfter(xNode,        xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("disasters")[0].LastChild);
            **xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("victims")[0].InsertAfter(xNode1, xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("victims")[0].LastChild);**

            xDoc.Save("C:\\4 ITP la laaa\\me doing\\disasters.xml");
            Label1.Text=("Apended");
```

Comment: Do you have to use XmlDocument? This is so much easier and more readable with XDoucment.

Comment: can you please help me in this question. i want to add a separate disaster details to a existing disaster details. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems way too complicated. I only fixed the `**` one.

```
xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("disasters")[0].InsertAfter(xNode, 
    xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("disasters")[0].LastChild);

//xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("victims")[0].InsertAfter(xNode1, 
//       xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("victims")[0].LastChild);
xNode.AppendChild(xNode1);  // <visitors> is simply a direct child of <disaster>
```

---

The preferred way with `using System.Xml.Linq;`

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("ExistingFile.xml");

XElement newDisaster = new XElement("disaster", 
        new XAttribute("ID", 2),
        new XAttribute("location", "Galle"),
        ...
        new XElement("victims", 
           new XElement("victim", 
              new XAttribute("type", "children"),
              ...
       )));

xDoc.Element("disasters").Add(newDisaster);
xDoc.Save("SomeFileName.xml");
```

Comment: here i want to add <victims> tag after the disaster tag. then i want to add <victim> tag inside it and append attributes to it. can you please tell me how to add  <victims> tag after disaster id. Thanks

Comment: I think you mean "victims tag _inside_ the disaster tag." That's very different. Both my answers do that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. i dont know about Linq. but if you could help me to add <victims> tag after disaster tag i would be much thankful to you

Comment: <victims>
          <victim type="adult"
               gender="male"
               amount="46"
               />
        <victim type="children"
             gender="female"
             amount="460"/>
      </victims> This is the one – Henk Holterman

Comment: My example shows exactly that. If something is unclear then you should specify what.  Watch your `()` and use indenting for readability.

Comment: Thanks Henk i could resolve my problem in your way. Thank you very much again